# System.ArgumentException when using RangeValidator

Tags: c#, type-conversion

So, in a MyBO class i have:

```
[NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "Cannot be null!")]
    [RangeValidator(0, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 20, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, Ruleset="validate_x1")]
    public byte x1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

And in a test class:

```
        [TestMethod()]
    public void x1Test()
    {
        MyBO target = new MyBO() { x1 = (byte)20 };
        ValidationResults vr = Validation.Validate(target, "validate_x1");
        Assert.IsTrue(vr.IsValid);
    }
```

Why i got: Test method TestProject.CatedraBOTest.x1Test threw exception:  System.ArgumentException: Object must be of type Int32.. ?

I really don't understand.
If i remove the RangeValidator everything works fine.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what @Jason said, look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.validators.rangevalidatorattribute.rangevalidatorattribute.aspx) where **none** of the constructor accept byte as parameter for range validation.

Having said that, you could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee761763.aspx) if you still want to compare it with byte. In that case, it could look like

```
[RangeValidator(typeof(Byte), "0", RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, "20", RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive)]
```

Note that the above line is written based on what I could see & interpret of the documentation. I have not written code to test if this works.

This is just to give you an idea of how things might work.

EDIT: The alternative could be to change the type of the property from byte to int.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the RangeValidator attribute does not work on BYTE values?

If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309347.aspx) it says:

> The Range Validator can be used with
>   any type that implements the
>   IComparable interface

I don't believe that BYTE is one of those types?

EDIT: I stand corrected, the BYTE data type does implement IComparable (just checked in Reflector) so I'm not sure now what the issue is. I'll keep looking.....

EDIT: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727017/using-rangevalidator-with-byte) which might help.